# Assigning multiple keys to JSON

Tags: python, json

I am retrieving data from a SQL server database that I would like to send to a web-service.  The server is expecting the JSON in a certain format as specified below.   My output now doesn't appear how I would like it to and cannot be consumed by the server.  How do I add the keys as specified below?  I am using Python 2.6.7.

```
   {
    "MetaData": {},
    "SRData": {
        "AddressVerified": "Y",
        "SRNumber": "1-16774241",
        "SRType": "Electronic Waste"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
    import pyodbc
    import json
    import collections
    import requests

        connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=url;DATABASE=ServiceRequest; UID=SA;PWD=pwd'
        conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("""
                    SELECT SRNUMBER, FirstName, LastName, ParentNumber
         FROM MYLA311 """)

        rows = cursor.fetchall()

 metadata =  '{ "MetaData": {},"SRData":'

    objects_list = []
    for row in rows:
         d = collections.OrderedDict()
         d['SRNUMBER']= row.SRNUMBER
         d['FirstName']= row.FirstName
         d['LastName']= row.LastName
         d['ParentNumber']= row.ParentNumber


    objects_list.append(d)

    output = {
    metadata:  objects_list

        j = json.dumps(output)
        objects_file = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\JSONOutput.txt'
        f = open(objects_file,'w')



        url = "https://posttestserver.com/post.php"
        data = j
        headers = {'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '/'}
        r = requests.post(url, data= json.dumps(output), headers=headers,  verify=False)
        conn.close()
```

Current Output:

```
{
    "{ \"MetaData\": {},\"SRData\":": [
        {
            "FirstName": "MyLAG", 
            "LastName": "ThreeEleven", 
            "ParentNumber": "021720151654176723", 
            "SRNUMBER": "1-3580171"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You likely need to tag the question with the Python server framework you're using. (I don't happen to recognize it offhand)

Comment: Your code is very broken. I’ve tried to fix it but that would have included a lot guessing. Please fix it yourself.

Comment: Can you please explain what is broken about it?   It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you are passing text in this line:

```
metadata =  '{ "MetaData": {},"SRData":'
```

remember that json.dumps makes a python dictionary to json so forget about the single quotes

```
metadata =  { "MetaData": {},"SRData":
```

then `objects_list` is an array, so it will put the brackets`[]`, if you need to get many rows, then its ok, but in your first JSON layout there are no arrays, just put the `d = collections.OrderedDict()` after the `SRDATA:`

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching the problem the wrong way. What you think you need to do is inject JSON syntax in between to get your end result, but what in stead you need to do is get the object you're serializing (formatting as JSON) to reflect the JSON structure you want to output.

In other words, if you have `dict` that has the exact same structure as your JSON, you're set:

```
import json
json.dumps(
   {"MetaData": {}, 
    "SRData": {"AddressVerified": "Y", 
           "SRNumber": "1-16774241", 
           "SRType": "Electronic Waste"}})
```

I'll leave making this dynamic to you :)

Comment: I am missing something here; I basically need to wrap my output with `{"MetaData": {}, 
    "SRData":`   Are you suggesting that my input dict and output JSON are the same and wrap that with json.dumps`{"MetaData": {}, 
    "SRData":`?  If I can simply append this, that would solve my issue.

Comment: That is pretty much what I am suggesting. The convenient truth is that Python and JSON have the same syntax for what Python calls "dicts" and JSON calls "Object literals". But don't let that fool you, that's merely accidental (if not historically related).